# Python creating multiple array from a basis array

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, spyder

Given an array `[x1 x2 x3 ... xn]` containing *n* elements, it is desired to produce such following array containing K rows:

```
[[x1   x2   x3   ... xn],
 [x1^2 x2^2 x3^2 ... xn^2],
 [x1^3 x2^3 x3^3 ... xn^3],
 ...,
 [x1^K x2^K x3^K ... xn^K]].
```

How to get this **efficiently** ?

Comment: can you show what you have tried so that we can suggest how to optimize your solution

Comment: So you have one array, `[x1   x2   x3   ... xn]` that you want to raise to the powers `[1,2,3,...k]`.  I assume the ^ is meant to be a power, usually denoted in Python as **.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variation on the `power.outer` using the ** operator and broadcasting:

```
In [223]: np.arange(1,5)**np.arange(1,4)[:,None]                                
Out[223]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 1,  4,  9, 16],
       [ 1,  8, 27, 64]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy.power.outer`:

```
>>> K=9
>>> numpy.power.outer(numpy.array([1, 4, 5]), numpy.arange(1, K+1)).T
array([[      1,       4,       5],
       [      1,      16,      25],
       [      1,      64,     125],
       [      1,     256,     625],
       [      1,    1024,    3125],
       [      1,    4096,   15625],
       [      1,   16384,   78125],
       [      1,   65536,  390625],
       [      1,  262144, 1953125]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at an algorithm with time complexity of O(kn):

```py
def build_value_lists(base_numbers, max_exponent):
    value_lists = []
    for k in range(1, max_exponent+1):
        values = []
        for x in base_numbers:
            values.append(x**k)
        value_lists.append(values)

    return value_lists

base_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
max_exponent = 3

print build_value_lists(base_numbers, max_exponent)
```

Since you need a Python list with all of the values, it's going to be difficult to make this algorithm much more efficient. If you just want the code to run faster, then note that threading is not likely to improve performance. [Multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) would be your best bet. The idea would be to create a pool of workers, each calculating the results of a single list for one value of `k`. As each worker completes its task, the results can be appended to the encompassing list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`PolynomialFeatures`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures)

Test column:

```
import numpy as np
col = np.linspace(1, 5, 5).reshape((-1, 1))
```

Transform:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=4, include_bias=False)
poly.fit_transform(col).T

> array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.],
         [  1.,   4.,   9.,  16.,  25.],
         [  1.,   8.,  27.,  64., 125.],
         [  1.,  16.,  81., 256., 625.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a matrix repeating the array K times and then use numpy's cumprod()

```
result = np.cumprod([arr,]*k,axis=0)
```

If you're not using numpy, a regular python list can do the same using accumulate from itertools.

```
result = accumulate( ([arr]*k), func=lambda a,b: [x*y for x,y in zip(a,b)])
```

This will be much slower than using numpy though.

*note: accumulate returns an iterator, you can turn it back into a list with `list(result)`*

Answer (score 0):

This is very famous matrix, it is called [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). There is a special function in Numpy package to get this matrix:

```
import numpy as np 
np.fliplr(np.vander([2,3,4], 5)).T


> array([[  1,   1,   1],
       [  2,   3,   4],
       [  4,   9,  16],
       [  8,  27,  64],
       [ 16,  81, 256]])
```